# ZipArchive: using getFromName() after addFile() doesn't works

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm trying use the method [`getFromName($name)`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getfromname.php) after I add the file via [`addFile($name)`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) or [`addFromString($name, $contents)`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php).

On my case, I'm not loading an existing zip file, but I'm creating it in a temporary directory, by using [`open($name)`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php).

---

The file is added normally and when I do a `var_dump()` over `ZipArchive` instance, I get:

```
class ZipArchive {
  public $status    => int(0)
  public $statusSys => int(0)
  public $numFiles  => int(1)
  public $filename  => string(45) "C:\Temp\Zip576D.tmp"
  public $comment   => string(0)  ""
}
```

Note that `$numFiles` shows `1` correctly, and if I call [`close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php) it will create file normally with this file added. But if I use `getFromName("test")` it always returns `false` instead of file contents.

---

You can run the code example here: [**live example**](https://ideone.com/e6YGcq)

```
<?php

    $archive = new ZipArchive;
    $archive->addFromString('test.bin', 'test');

    $status = $archive->getFromName('test.bin');

    echo $status === false ? 'FAIL' : 'SUCCESS: ' . $status;

?>
```

---

Related: [**bugs.php.net:** Cannot decompress newly added files.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41456)

Comment: **Just a note:** if I `close()` and `open()` the same file, then `getFromName()` works as expected. The problem is that in this process the file is compressed all the time.

Comment: From that bugs.php.net link you posted, it seems this is by design. As "all operations are applied to the zip file on close." Until `flush()` is added to ZipArchive, I don't think there is a solution apart from a close/open. Might want to rethink your approach, and design your code such that you don't need to read a file right after adding it. My 2 cents.

Comment: @jszobody I'm doing that current now. Seems that `flush()` will not works, this bug is from 2007. :/

Comment: You call the variable status as if you're checking to see if the file was added correctly. Why not capture the return value of `addFromString`? It seems to do exactly what you want already.

Comment: Yes, I'm capturing it. But it basically double the memory usage, because the ZipArchive instance have this content and now my class too.

Comment: 6 years on, and this is still a problem btw. 15 years on, and still no `flush()`!